# $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Show that $P\cap H$ is contained in a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ a group, let $H$ a subgroup of $G$ and let $P\in\operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$. Show that $P\cap H$ is a subset of some $U\in\operatorname{Syl}_p(H)$.

I know that \begin{align} |G| &=p^a\cdot nk,\\ |H| &=p^b\cdot n, \\ |P| &=p^a\end{align} for $b\leq a, (p,n),(p,k)=1$. The trivial case is $a=b$, but i don't know how to handle the case $b<a$.

Comment: @J.Doe.It's  Sylow and it is  pronounced as "See-loe"

Comment: @DavidMitra If $|G|=p^a\cdot m$ for some prime $p, 0\leq a$ and $(p,m)=1$ then p-Silow subgroups family denoted by $\operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$ is the family of all the subgroups of $G$ of order $p^a$.

Comment: @ChinnapparajR Technically it's pronounced "see-lov".

Comment: @YuvalGat: Yes! agreed!

Comment: A fun generalistion-of-a-special-case that, despite being an algebraist, I found so implausible that I disbelieved it when someone told me:  if $P$ is normal in $G$, then $H \cap P$ *is* a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a little hint: 
what's the order of the elements of $P \cap H $ ? 
Then use Sylow's theorem to deduce that this is contain in a P-sylow of H.

Comment: I think it may make more sense just to ask what is the order of $P \cap H$ itself, to avoid the application of Cauchy's theorem that looking at the order of its elements would require.

Comment: Don't need Cauchy's Theorem. A P-Sylow is in particular a p-group. So all the elements in $ P \cap H $ have order a power of $ p $. It's a p-group, then you can apply Sylow's theorem.

Comment: Yes, but you're stating the converse of what is needed.  Your argument will show that all the elements of $P \cap H$ have order a $p$-power; but then one needs Cauchy's theorem to show that $P \cap H$ is a $p$-group (in the sense that its order is a $p$-power), which is easier to establish directly because the order of $P \cap H$ divides that of $P$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just misread what you wrote. You are absolutely right, Lagrange theorem better applies here.

Answer (score 1):

Being the intersection of two subgroups, $P \cap H$ is a subgroup. Moreover, it is contained in $P$, so it has order $p^k$ for some $k$.

Let $Q$ be a maximal $p$-subgroup of $H$ that contains $P \cap H$. It has to exist since you can take $Q_0 = P \cap H$, and then search for a bigger $Q_1$. If you can't find it, then $Q=Q_0$. Otherwise, take $Q_1$ and search for a bigger $Q_2$, and so on. This process has to terminate, since $H$ is finite.

The key is that now, from Sylow's theorems, we know that **every** maximal $p$-subgroup of $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$. So take $U=Q$ and you are done.